# How do I read a file line-by-line using an asunchronous method NIO?

Tags: java, nio

I'd like to read a text file line-by-line, using `AsynchronousFileChannel.read()` with a `CompletionHandler`.

The only functionality I can find that does a line-by-line reading is `BufferedReader.readLine()`, but it's coupled with the blocking nature of the reader.

Is there any similar solution for this, or must I read the entire file and then wrap it with a BufferedReader ?

Comment: Why? Just use BufferedReader.readLine(). Why do you think you need asynchronous behaviour?

Comment: I want to be able to scale-up on the number of concurrent operations. This requires me not to "waste" the application's thread but rather use it for something else while the data is being read from the disk.

Comment: But files aren't really read line by line, they are read in buffer loads.